# Assigning initial value to VHDL vector

Tags: vhdl

I am just learning the syntax of VHDL
I'd like to assign an initial value of `'1'` to `Qout(0)` and the rest `'0'`.

I cannot find the reference that shows me the correct syntax.

This gave me an error:

```vhdl
signal Qout: Std_Logic_Vector (4 downto 0) :='1';
```

Comment: We'd use a string literal as the initial expression, along the lines of "00001". The type of the string literal is determined by context. There's an implicit subtype conversion (bounds, direction). There has to be a matching element in expression for each element of the object. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.4.2 Elaboration of a declaration, 14.4.2.5 Object declarations.  Also see 9.3 Operands, 9.3.2 Literals. The type of a character literal ('1') is determined by overload resolution and none matches the base type of std_logic_vector. 12.5 The context of overload resolution.

Comment: An enumeration type (5.2.2) declaration also declares it's enumeration values (character literals, and/or identifiers).  std_logic_vector is an array types (5.3.2 Array types) who's element base type is an enumerated type (std_ulogic, a character enumeration type). There's a requirement that the character value of each element of the string is an enumeration value of the element type  (std_ulogic) of the array type (std_logic_vector).

Comment: The syntax describing the use of a string as an expression is found in the BNF in 9. Expressions, 9.1, where we find a primary can be a literal. So it's not syntax error, it's semantic. ghdl for instance gives `error: can't match character literal '1' with type array type "std_logic_vector"`. Which tells us there is no overload resolution for '1' with type std_logic_vector, a semantic requirement. What's the actual error message from your tool?

Comment: The semantic error is found in 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations - "If the signal declaration includes the assignment symbol followed by an expression, it shall be of the same type as the signal. Such an expression is said to be a _default expression_. The default expression defines a default value associated with the signal or, for a composite signal, with each scalar subelement thereof. ... For a signal declared to be of a composite subtype, each scalar subelement of the value of the default expression is the default value of the corresponding subelement of the signal."

Answer (score 1):

As user1155120 says, in VHDL the width of the right hand side has to match the width of the left hand side of an *assignment operator* (`<=` or `:=`).

So, you could use the *literal* that corresponds to a `std_logic_vector`, which is a `string`:

```
signal Qout: Std_Logic_Vector (4 downto 0) := "00001";
```

(a `string` literal in VHDL is enclosed within double quotes). Or (and this is what a more experience VHDL user would do) use an *aggregate*:

```
signal Qout: Std_Logic_Vector (4 downto 0) := (0 => '1', others => '0');
```

The construct on the right hand side is an aggregate. An aggregate is a construct for representing *composite data types* such as *arrays* (which is what a `std_logic_vector` is) and *record types* (like a struct in C). The above example is saying "make element 0 equal to `'1'` and make all the other elements equal to `'0'`. Element 0 is the right hand side, because the array was declared `(4 downto 0)` (not `(0 to 4)`).

Using an aggregate might be considered a better way of doing it because, whilst not to clear to a beginner, the code is more maintainable: if the width of the signal were to change, you would not have to modify the aggregate.

---

You might want to seriously consider why you want to initialise this signal at all. If you are using an FPGA, it may be the case that that the corresponding flip-flops will be initialised as you wish. (I assume this signal `Qout` will become 5 flip-flops because of the name you have chosen.) On a chip this would never ever be the case - your initialisation would be ignored. You might want to consider whether providing a reset to your flip-flops would be a better solution than initialising a signal, eg an *active-high synchronous reset*:

```
process (Clock)
begin
  if Reset = '1' then
    Qout <= (0 => '1', others => '0');
  elsif rising_edge(Clock) then 
    ...
```

Comment: There is also the option of enhance bit string literals from VHDL 2008:  `signal Qout: Std_Logic_Vector (4 downto 0) := 5x"1";`

Comment: IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 8.4.3.1 Object declarations b) Signal declarations "The initial value expression shall be ignored unless the declaration is in a package, where the declaration shall have an initial value expression." FPGA vendors do not support signal declarations in packages, e.g. ug901 Vivado User Guide Synthesis, VHDL Support, VHDL Objects, Signals, declared in an architecture declarative part, or block - _external_ block. IEEE Std 1076-2008 3.1 - found in the entity header 3.2.2 port clause 6.5.6.3 or entity declarative part 3.2.3, not block statements.

Comment: You'll also find Vivado supports initial values using constant for registers (ug901, VHDL Support, VHDL Initial Values and Operational Set/Reset), which varies from Matthew's answer and the withdrawn standard.